# Using <= for every dependency in case of following semantic versioning idea

Tags: versioning, dependencies, semantic-versioning

As [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) (and common sense) declares - the major version is incremented in case if non backward compatible change is introduced.

Now let's assume we have a project called `Project` that has a current version `1.0.42` and a library `Lib` it depends on that is of a `2.1.3` version at the moment.

Does that mean that following semver ideology we should constraint the dependency of the `Project` to be `Depends: Lib (< 3)`?

From my experience - no one does that, but I find it semantically correct and very self-descriptive.

What do you think of this?

Comment: Technically, `Lib (>= 2.x, < 3)` where x is the minor version that introduced the latest feature you rely on (perhaps a patch version too if you depend on a recent bug fix) would be safer, as it rules out 2.(x-1) which your code wouldn't work with.

Comment: @delnan: would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: My guess is that semantic versioning isn't followed widely and strictly enough for people to generally depend on it.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: you still need to follow some convention

Comment: @zerkms: As author of `Project`, does the fact that `Lib` has version`2.1.3` guarantee you that the authors of `Lib` strictly follow semantic versioning? Perhaps they don't and remove a function in version `2.2`.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: indeed, for 3rd party app I mostly use strict equal to version. My question was more about private practice: I produce multiple libraries for internal usage and can guarantee whatever I need :-)

Answer (score 3):

The RubyGems package management system has the *pessimistic version constraint* for precisely this reason:

```
~> 1.2.3
```

means "chop off the last component of the version number and treat it is a wildcard, but don't use a version less than specified", IOW

```
~> 1.2.3
```

means

```
1.2.* && >= 1.2.3
```

and

```
~> 1.2.3.4
```

means

```
1.2.3.* && >= 1.2.3.4
```

In other words, it means: any version at least as new as the one that was specified, but only within the same "category". So, if you specify a bugfix release, you will get newer bugfix releases but no new minor version. If you specify a minor verso, you will get newer minor versions but no new major version.